# How to make smooth transition between display: block and display: none in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make a smooth transition here? I've been trying many things but nothing seems to work for me. Can you help me out on this one? I want smooth transition between when the section is visible and when it hides

```js
      function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
        var y = document.getElementById("plus");
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
          x.style.display = "none";
          y.setAttribute("src", "images/down-arrow2.png");
        } else {
          x.style.display = "block";
          y.setAttribute("src", "images/up-arrow2.png");
        }
      }
```

```html
          <div id="myDIV">
            <section>
              Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
              industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
              ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
              type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            </section>
          </div>
          <div class="ex">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" id="expand">
              <img src="images/down-arrow2.png" id="plus" />
            </button>
          </div>
```

Comment: Nothing will be completely smooth since `display: none` removes the element from the document flow and will likely cause other elements to move. jQuery fades the element out using opacity before setting the display to none.

Comment: You could add a class with transitions (CSS) and a timeout to your click-func..

Answer (score 2):

As already correctly stated by @evolutionbox it will be impossible to do it the way you trying to do it.

`display: none;` removes an element from the flow and also in an absolute state. An element can either exist or not exist but not only partially exist.

As such we have to play with the height and remove the visibility of an element by giving it a `height: 0`. To prevent the visual overflow we combine it with `overflow: hidden`.

However, this would require to know the height. As such we use `max-height` and set the `max-height` to an insanely high value that will not be reached.

Last but not least, you should avoid the usage of `.style` in JS in 2022. Use `.classList` instead and apply the changes through CSS. `classList` will add, remove or toggle a class to that element. Using `.toggle('class-name')` in this case makes the JS code way shorter as we don't need an if/else statement anymore.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
  var y = document.getElementById("plus");
  x.classList.toggle('visible');
  if (x.classList.contains('visible') === true) {
    y.setAttribute("src", "https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg/ff0000");
  } else {
    y.setAttribute("src", "https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg/00ff00");
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  max-height: 0; /* makes the element invisible due to no height */
  overflow: hidden; /* hides the visual overflow when the elements height is smaller then the contents height */
  transition: max-height 0.75s ease-out; /* smooth-transition between both "states" */
  
}

#myDIV.visible {
  max-height: 1000vh; /* insanely high value */
  transition: max-height 0.75s ease-in; /* smooth-transition between both "states" */
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <section>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </section>
</div>
<div class="ex">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="expand">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg/00ff00" id="plus" />
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great. But it only seems to work for the first time when you press the button. You can see it goes smoothly, but when you wrap the content the transition is gone and also for the next time you try to open the content

Comment: what do you mean? The transition stays smooth and can open and closed multiple times within the snippet just fine.

Comment: Oh, pardon. You are right. I didn't remove the rest of my script. But I still want my arrows to change every time it opens and closes. Can you help me with this one?

Comment: update the JS code to change the image src. Just need to isnert the right path yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity` for transition smoothly:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var y = document.getElementById("plus");
x.style.opacity = "1";

function myFunction() {
  if (x.style.opacity === "1") {
    x.style.opacity = "0";
    x.style.transition = "1s opacity";
    y.setAttribute("src", "https://s6.uupload.ir/files/on-off-switch-sign-vector-8935407_ldx0.jpg");
    setTimeout(function(){x.style.display = "none"}, 1000);
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
    x.style.opacity = "0";
    setTimeout(function(){x.style.opacity = "1";}, 1000);
    y.setAttribute("src", "https://s6.uupload.ir/files/on-off-switch-web-icon-vector-8987917_2es3.jpg");
    
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <section>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </section>
</div>
<div class="ex">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="expand">
     <img src="https://s6.uupload.ir/files/on-off-switch-web-icon-vector-8987917_2es3.jpg" id="plus" />
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: that makes the element just invisible but will still contain all the space. Espacially if we talk about larger elements you will end up with insaely high white-space. The task ehre is a read more/less button if you look into the code and the way it is supposed to work.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks. I edited my answer. how is?

Comment: better. One last thing to adress: in 2022 you should avoid using `.style` in JS for varios reasons incl. specificity weight issues. Changes applies through CSS ('.classList`) should be prefered.

Answer (score 0):

like takoshi i prefer realizing the changes and transitions with CSS whenever possible.
To change the background smoothly, I would insert two div-container with the images as background image. Now change / flip the opacity of them both per transition.
So you get some more CSS, but this is all really simple stuff.
JavaScript is only needed, to toggle the classes. I do it per classList.add and classList.remove, but you can use toggle as well.

```js
function myFunction() {
  let myDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (myDiv.classList.contains('hidden')) {
    myDiv.classList.remove('hidden') ;
    document.getElementById("expand").classList.add('hide');
  } else {
    document.getElementById("expand").classList.remove('hide');
    myDiv.classList.add('hidden' );
  }
}
```

```css
#myDIV{
  opacity: 1.0 ;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out ;
}
#myDIV.hidden{
  opacity: 0.0 ;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out ;
}
#expand{
  position: relative ;
  height: 50px ;
  width: 50px ;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out ;
}
#expand .button_inner{
  position: absolute ;
  top: 0px ;
  left: 0px ;
  width: 50px ;
  height: 50px ;
}
#expand .show{
  opacity: 1.0 ;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out ;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg/00ff00') ;
}
#expand .hide{
  opacity: 0.0 ;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out ;
  background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/50.jpg/ff0000') ;
}
#expand.hide .show{
  opacity: 0.0 ;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out ;
}
#expand.hide .hide{
  opacity: 1.0 ;
  transition: all 0.8s ease-in-out ;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <section>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
  industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
  ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of
  type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  </section>
</div>
<div class="ex">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" id="expand" class="hide">
    <div class="button_inner show"></div>
    <div class="button_inner hide"></div>

  </button>
</div>
```